# How to use credential function in jenkins file which has node, stage

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I am not getting google credentials when i am using the below code.
def GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS    = credentials('XYZ Credentials')

Answer (score 6):

[Edited]

Please check this official [guide](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials) to see if you have defined it correctly.

Also check if you're passing credentials ID, not a description to `credentials()` method.

If you're using Jenkins pipelines, you also can try [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/).
From plugin [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin), a typical example of a username password type credential would look like:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'amazon', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
  // available as an env variable, but will be masked if you try to print it out any which way
  // note: single quotes prevent Groovy interpolation; expansion is by Bourne Shell, which is what you want
  sh 'echo $PASSWORD'
  // also available as a Groovy variable
  echo USERNAME
  // or inside double quotes for string interpolation
  echo "username is $USERNAME"
}
```

For scripted pipeline you can use `withCredentials()` as well (see [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/)):

```
node {
  withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'mylogin', variable: 'USERPASS')]) {
    sh '''
      set +x
      curl -u "$USERPASS" https://private.server/ > output
    '''
  }
}
```

Or you can use `withEnv()` section:

```
node {
    withEnv(["CREDS=credentials('jenkins-creds')"]) {
        stage('Build') {
            sh 'printenv'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: def GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS = credentials('XYZ credentials')
sh 'echo ****** $GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS ****'
This is not working

Comment: Did you use `credentials()` method in the `environment` directive? (See [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials)).
E.g., 


    `environment {
        BITBUCKET_COMMON_CREDS = credentials('jenkins-bitbucket-common-creds')
    }`

Comment: Or, probably, you're passing credentials description to `credentials()` method, not a credential ID. In that case, you must specify ID of your credentials.

Comment: I am using node instead of pipeline in jenkins file.

Comment: If you're using node, it's called scripted pipeline. So, for scripted pipeline you can use withCredentials() or withEnv() section (updated in answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example

```
node { 
    stage('Preparing env') {
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'XYZ Credentials', passwordVariable: 'GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_PSW', usernameVariable: 'GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_USR')]) {
            // Do something here with your username and password variables
        }
    }
}
```